# Highcharts timeline, markers behind gridLine issue

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm making a timeline Highcharts graph, and I have an issue where some of the markers, from partiular series, are shown behind the gridLine.

I read that since they are drawn as svg paths, it is the paths drawn last that is shown on top. But I'm not sure I can control when the gridline is drawn.

I found a jsfiddle that seems to have the same issue as me:
https://jsfiddle.net/oa3j8429/

I *could* set the lineWidth to 0, but I would prefer not to, as I need to show different colors on the line:

```
plotOptions: {
    timeline: {
        linewidth: 0
```

Any ideas on how to get all the markers on top of the gridline?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jesper F., Markers and line from one series is in a separate group. Do you want to keep different color on the line? If not, you can modify grid line: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mLfcgaz3/ If yes, the simplest solution seems to be to draw an additional line by using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thanks for your reply. I see, now I understand the issue better. However, I do need the line to be in different colors, and I need to change the line color based on a data set. So I don't think the Highcharts.SVGRenderer is an option unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's not a problem, you can easily adapt the rendered line to your chart. Please check this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8uaqzcv1/

Comment: @ppotaczek I'm not entirely sure why this line goes behind the other series. The onload must be run before I guess. But it works - thanks a lot!

Comment: You can always check how `zIndex` is handled internally: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/ed63271415f908f023bc8b567a9d2aa32262e0db/ts/Core/Renderer/SVG/SVGElement.ts#L295